# Getting authenticate with AFOAuth2Manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, afoauth2client

I am working on a dribbble client and I am having trouble getting authenticate using the AFOAuth2Manager. I am currently using NXOAuth2Client but I just came across AFOAuth2Manager so I would like to give it a go.

With NXOAuthClient, I have no problem getting a token from the server. However when it comes to AFOAuth2Manager it always returns an error.

This is what I used to init with NXOAuth2Client:

```
    [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] setClientID:kDRBClientID
                                             secret:kDRBClientSecret
                                              scope:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"public", @"write", @"comment", @"upload", nil]
                                   authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kDRBAuthorizationURL]
                                           tokenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kDRBTokenURL]
                                        redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kDRBRedirectURL]
                                      keyChainGroup:kDRBAccountType
                                     forAccountType:kDRBAccountType];
```

Using the same constant I am trying to init with AFOAuth2Manager like this:

```
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kDRBBaseUrl];
    AFOAuth2Manager *OAuth2Manager =
    [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                    clientID:kDRBClientID
                                      secret:kDRBClientSecret];
    OAuth2Manager.useHTTPBasicAuthentication = NO;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"scope" : @"public write",
                                 @"redirect_uri" : kDRBRedirectURL};
     [OAuth2Manager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/oauth/authorize"
                                            parameters:dictionary
                                               success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                                   NSLog(@"Token: %@", credential.accessToken);
                                               }
                                               failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                               }];
```

The flow of sign in for dribbble first direct user to the sign in page (which is the /oauth/authorize page), after user enters the username and password, it will redirect user to the redirectURL given.

My problem right now is that I couldn't even get to the sign-in page. Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong? (I also tried the different authenticate methods from AFOAuth2Manager but none of them works).

I am very new to OAuth2 so please bear with me.

**Update**

Here's the error log:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: client error (422)" UserInfo=0x7fb02ad2de00 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fb02ad6e200> { URL: https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize } { status code: 422, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 47;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 08 Aug 2015 23:52:20 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
    Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
    "X-Request-Id" = "8489a5f0-206a-48ff-b6e7-81664fc6b6f5";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.006667";
} }
```

With NXOAuth2Client, it will prepare a url for the sign in page with my params like this:

https: //dribbble.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=my_client_id&scope=write%20comment%20upload%20public&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri&response_type=code

but I noticed that with AFOAuth2 it throws error at https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize. It doesn't append my params to the request url?

Comment: What's the error? update the error in question.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line before making the request

```
OAuth2Manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

And, [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) - Server was unable to process the contained instructions. The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.

For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the suggested line to the code but it's throwing the same error.